# What do you use to upload your files (code/documents) to a live server?

Tags: ftp, file-upload, diff, rsync

rsync
zsync

Is there any other better sync/backup tool available on linux. I have a local installation of my site, a wiki. I wish to make changes to my local site both in terms of wiki content/ and plugins/templates, and then just wish to press a button :D or run the command over a folder, it should check for the diff for my local files vs live-site files, and does the needful in the direction i wish. Lets say only one direction from local-machine to live-site.
That is why filezilla/ cuteFTP will not work for as they donot perform any Diff, will very inefficiently just replace the full folder.
It will be awesome if there is any frontend available to rsync/zsync. Preferably zsync as the site, it is tweaked for http transfers.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/39804/best-syncing-tool

Comment: Pardon me, for first few mins I did not get any responses on SF, SO has more traffic. Therefore i asked at SO, as i think so many programmers must facing similar issues for their personal project hosting. Anyways ps feel free to close. i got a good answer at SF, but i will keep this question on, as i might get a better answer here. thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got an answer from SF, if people are interested, try SiteCopy.

> http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/

it does exactly what is required. Well thats what the site says, I still have to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a distributed version control system such as Mercurial or git. Then you would make your changes, commit to your local repository, and then push the changes to your server.

Comment: Yes exactly that is what i want... but the problem is its a free hosting site, and i cannot install any SCM over there?  
So that is i think any tool working on the lines of ftp with diff in-built

Comment: Well you could just commit locally then push the files that were modified in your commit to the remote server then.